# Program for Python that traces back code of a function call or instantiation and nicely prints it all out

Tags: python, function, pretty-print, traceback

Some projects are so big that in order to understand for example a function call requires you to go through many different blocks of code all throughout the project(e.g. in projects with scarcely documented api's). Many times just looking at it isn't always enough, I need to often write it down because you need to look back and forth between the different code blocks.

Is there any program that allows you to insert a function/method or class and get a complete traceback report for that with all the code it calls upon? It would also be handy if at the same time that program showed you the directory structure of that code.

Edit

====

I refined my question in [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037109/a-function-in-traceback-inspect-cgitb-that-gives-a-pretty-traceback-for-any-give). I would prefer not to startup a gui for this process each time. Just one python function call to get the trace output seems the best solution.

Comment: Looked at the `traceback` module in the standard library?

Comment: You seem to be looking for an IDE.  See http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments

Comment: @cdarke. Could you be more specific? Say for example I wanted to get a complete trace on the function `pyglet.application.run()`. How can I do this with traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is from [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037109/getting-a-python-traceback-without-an-exception/11038685#comment14498861_11038685).

```
import trace

def trapy(arg):
    tracer = trace.Trace()
    tracer.run(arg)
    r = tracer.results()
    r.write_results()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import module_name
    trapy('module_name.function_name()')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for the [python debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), or the GUI version [WinPDB](http://winpdb.org/) that will allow you to follow execution of a python program and with breakpoints correctly set (in the `__init__` of the class you want to instanciate), you will be able to see all the traceback that leaded to the instanciation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what excactly you want to focus on (just function names? return values? methods?) you could implement different things by just using the [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function. The function you pass to that will be called for every execution and you can customize a traceback to your needs. Bellow I have an example that I use whenver I have to understand the flow of a new program/package.

**Source:**

```
import sys, inspect

class Tracer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tracing_packages = []
        self.whitespace = '    '
        self.indent_lvl = 0

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        # Module info
        mod = inspect.getmodule(frame)
        if mod:
            modpath = mod.__name__
        else:
            modpath = '<no module>'
        # Just return if not interested in package
        for to_trace in self.tracing_packages:
            if not modpath.startswith(to_trace):
                return self.trace
        # Other info
        fn_name = frame.f_code.co_name
        src_lines = inspect.getsource(frame).split('\n')
        src_line_start = src_lines[0]
        src_line_end = src_lines[-1]
        lineno = frame.f_lineno
        ws = self.whitespace
        # Printing
        if event == 'call':
            self.indent_lvl += 1
            print('%scallin: %s %s %s' % (self.indent_lvl*ws, modpath, fn_name, str(arg)))
        elif event == 'return':
            if isinstance(arg, object):
                ret = type(arg)
            else:
                ret = str(arg)
            print('%sreturn: %s' % (self.indent_lvl*ws, ret))
            self.indent_lvl -= 1
        return self.trace

    def watch_package(self, packname):
        self.tracing_packages.append(packname)
```

**Example**

Here I just want to understand the flow of a package called [PyOCD](https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD):

```
>>> import sys, inspect, pyOCD
>>> tracer = Tracer()
>>> tracer.watch_package('pyOCD')
>>> sys.settrace(tracer.trace)
>>> pyOCD.board.MbedBoard.listConnectedBoards()
    callin: pyOCD.board.mbed_board listConnectedBoards None
        callin: pyOCD.board.mbed_board getAllConnectedBoards None
            callin: pyOCD.interface.pyusb_backend getAllConnectedInterface
                callin: pyOCD.interface.pyusb_backend __init__ None
                    callin: pyOCD.interface.interface __init__ None
                    return: <type 'NoneType'>
                return: <type 'NoneType'>
                callin: pyOCD.interface.pyusb_backend start_rx None
                return: <type 'NoneType'>
            return: <type 'list'>

            ...
```

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/Pithikos/09ed1aeabebad7b9eb87) is a version that prints return values and function arguments in a clear way.