# Getting a python traceback without an exception

Tags: python, stack-trace, pretty-print

Suppose you have these modules:

### module1.py

```
import module2

def a():
    module1.b()

def c():
    print "Hi guys!"
```

### module2.py

```
import module1

def b():
    module1.c()
```

I want a function `func(a())` that produces a similar output to this: (=a traceback ?)

```
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test/module1.py
   3 def a():
   4     module1.b()

   1 import module1

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test/module2.py
   3 def b():
   4     module1.c()

   1 import module2

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test/module1.py
   6 def c():
   7     print "Hi guys!"
```

It might be possible with the standard modules `traceback` and/or `cgitb` and/or `inspect` but I am having a hard time figuring out these modules from the documentation.

I thought it was possible doing `traceback.print_stack(a())` but it just kept on loading forever for some reason. I tried other functions in those modules but without success.

### UPDATE 3

@jterrace

python trapy_module.py :

```
import trace

def trapy(arg):
    tracer = trace.Trace()
    tracer.run(arg)
    r = tracer.results()
    r.write_results()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    trapy('random.random()')
```

Now when I do:
`python trapy_module.py` I get:

```
--- modulename: trapy, funcname: <module>
<string>(1):
```

Replacing `import random` with `import pyglet` and `random.random()` with `pyglet.app.run()` just keeps running without outputting anything.

Comment: ITYM `module2.b()` or alternatively `from module2 import b`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[traceback.print_stack](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack) works nicely for me:

```
>>> import traceback
>>> def what():
...    traceback.print_stack()
... 
>>> def hey():
...    what()
... 
>>> hey()
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in hey
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in what
```

**UPDATE:**

You've made it clear you really don't want a traceback. You want tracing information. Here's a way you can get some trace info:

```
#tracetest.py

def what():
    return 3

def hey():
    return what()

def yo():
    return hey()

import trace
tracer = trace.Trace()
tracer.run("yo()")
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results()
```

and running the above:

```
$ python tracetest.py
 --- modulename: tracetest, funcname: <module>
<string>(1):   --- modulename: tracetest, funcname: yo
tracetest.py(8):     return hey()
 --- modulename: tracetest, funcname: hey
tracetest.py(5):     return what()
 --- modulename: tracetest, funcname: what
tracetest.py(2):     return 3
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But I'd like to e.g. trace back `pyglet.app.run()` without needing to touch the [pyglet](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet/app/__init__.py) project code.

Comment: I think you want the trace module. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you again. This works in that example but not for some functions/object instantiations in other libraries apparently. Do you know why? See my update in the original post.

Comment: Were you running from the command line? Trace only works from files

Comment: Ow, I was. I ran it as a file now but still not what it should be. (see update 2 of the original post)

Comment: You are passing a function not a string. You need to pass "random.random()" not random.random()

Comment: I did pass a string, look at the third line of the `trapy` function: `tracer.run(str(arg))` .

Comment: No you didn't. str(random.random()) is NOT "random.random()"

Comment: Thank you for noticing this! I passed a string "random.random()" now (see edit 3), but the output is still the same though.

Comment: That's because random.random is a native call. You won't get tracing information for that.

Comment: There's a `random.py` file in `usr/lib/python2.7`, there are no `math.py` or the `sys.py` files in there. So I thought that was possible. But I guess it is because `random.random()` also makes use of other modules which are not written using only python(such as math). Thank you for your help.