# How to get full history executed function inside parrent function in Python / Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, trace, stack-trace, traceback

I have function like this

```
def test_func_1(angka):
    angka = angka + 3
    result = test_func_2(angka)
    return result

def test_func_2(angka):
    angka = angka + 5
    return test_func_3(angka)

def test_func_3(angka):
    angka = angka * 2
    return angka

def wrapper_func():
    return test_func_1(3)
```

When I call

```
wrapper_func()
```

I want to have history function that executed like this :

```
wrapper_func()
test_func_1(3)
test_func_2(angka)
test_func_3(angka)
```

is that possible ? I know it's possible if we put `trace_back.print_stack()` like this [Getting a python traceback without an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037109/getting-a-python-traceback-without-an-exception)

But what if I don't have access to change that code ?

It's very useful when I run django shell in the production server, and debug intermittent issue. So I can just call that function and I input specific parameter, then I can know what actually that function did

Comment: There's no way for `wrapper_func` to know where it has been.  If you're just looking for a trace, have you looked at the Python debugger?